# How should I route Angular 2 app in Tomcat?

Tags: angular, tomcat, routes

I'm bulding my first Angular 2 app and I deployed it in a Tomcat server.
When I first load my page, it goes to index.html page, the Angular 2 Route gets me to the right path and it works fine, but if I reload my page I get 404 error. I know it happens because Tomcat can't find the URL path. My doubt is: Every route I configure in Angular, do I have to configure it in Tomcat as well or there is another way?

I'm sorry if my doubt sounds a little bit fool, but I'm stucked in this.

Thanks.

Comment: You need to configure the server to support HTML5 pushState. This requires that all requests to invalid resources are redirected to `index.html`. You should be able to look up answers by this information.